# $x^n-dy^n$ irreducible?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, pell-type-equations

I am dealing right now with a generalized form of the Pell Equation. In order to use Thue's Theorem I need to know that $x^n-dy^n$ ist irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Somehow I don't get why. I tried to use Eisenstein over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ but that didn't work...

Comment: The result isn't true, e.g. $x^4 - 4y^4 = (x^2 - 2y^2)(x^2 + 2y^2)$. What conditions do you have on $d$?

Comment: @hunter Usually in the context of Pell's equation $d$ is square free.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention: As "always" with Pell equation d is positive and not a square @hunter.

Comment: squarefree or just not a square? if squarefree then Eisenstein works.

Comment: Example for non-square $x^3-8y^3=(x-2y)(x^2+2xy+4y^2)$ (hence why you need squarefree instead)

Comment: @Sil do I actually need squarefree? Shouldn't it be enough to have one primefactor, that we can find just once in the prime factorization of d in order to use Eisenstein? so eg $x^3-12y^3 should also be irreducible.

Comment: Yes, squarefree condition is just sufficient, not necessary. Non-square condition was not sufficient, nor necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If it was reducible then $ (x/y)^n-d$ would be reducible too. Replace $x/y$ by $z$ and apply Eisenstein.

Comment: Thank you, cool idea that that works!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the polynomial were reducible. Then it would be reducible after substituting $y=1$. But now you can apply Eisenstein, since $d$ is assumed squarefree.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense to me

Comment: One needs to be careful when checking irreducibility by choosing single $y$, for example if we had $(x^2+2)y$ (which is reducible), then for $y=1$ we get $x^2+2$ (which is irreducible).

Comment: @Sil you are quite right; to apply this technique we also need to note that the polynomial doesn't factor as a pure polynomial of $x$ times a pure polynomial of $y$.

Comment: Right, actually more generally it must not be divisible by any such polynomial (one of the two factors still can have both $x,y$ variables, for example $(x^2+2y^2)y$).